# SQL Server recovery with LVM snapshot as base

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, recovery

Is it possible to fully recover a database from a snapshot plus transaction log backups? By snapshot I mean a crash-consistent clone of the Server - in this case an LVM snapshot that is shipped offsite while the live server continues to operate and generate logs.

--edit

To clarify, the LVM snapshots are of the entire Virtual Machine including OS, SQL Server and everything else. This snapshot is then transported to a remote site and successfully started on the host. I know I can at this point restore a full backup and recover with the logs, but I wondered if it was possible to skip the full backup/restore step and use the snapshot as a base?

Comment: Are these SQL aware snapshots? Does SQL get told a backup is happening and freeze/quiesce the IOs and log that a backup took place?

Comment: @Mike no - they are as if someone has pulled the power cord

Comment: just to make sure we are on the same page. You mean a snapshot when the server is off and all services are stopped? Basically - SQL is always writing to the log and data file and that order and consistency needs to be maintained. If you take a snapshot with SQL running, you are not guaranteeing that consistency and will likely be unable to recover.

Comment: @Mike, I mean a snapshot of a running server - like a vss snapshot (though in this case I am using LVM). I will have transaction logs from before, during and after the snapshot available during recovery. I think you are saying recovery will not be possible in this scenario, is that right? My hope was that SQL Server would be able to return the 'crashed' database to a consistent state from the transaction logs and then continue to apply them beyond the point of the 'crash'

Comment: @JackDouglas - are you able to attach the database files from that LVM snapshot and have the database online?

Comment: @Marian yes - or rather I can bring the snapshot up as a new VM on the host at the DR site. Logs are shipped by a different mechanism but also arrive at the remote site.

Comment: But when you bring that snapshot up on the new VM and turn SQL on - is it good? Or is it corrupt?

Comment: @Mike it's good, not corrupt. It presumably performs some sort of crash recovery?

Comment: If this is an emergency, this might work: Delete the logs before starting the service. Put the DB into emergency mode. Perform a tail log backup and a full backup. Maybe you can then piece together the database by restoring all the logs you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to the first comment question...

> no - they are as if someone has pulled the power cord

You've got your answer.  They aren't a consistent backup, so SQL isn't aware that a backup happened so you can't put it into a restoring state and restore logs over it.

Answer (score 1):

Going from this: "I can at this point restore a full backup and recover with the logs, but I wondered if it was possible to skip the full backup/restore step and use the snapshot as a base?".

In order to restore the log backups the database needs to be put in a 'restoring' state. Now I'm not actually sure if you can put the online database in that state without actually making a real restore of a full backup. The normal way would be to restore the db from full backup using the NORECOVERY option (expects log backups) and then restore the following log backups.

I'm not sure if there's a way to circumvent it.

PS: Jack, you don't need to mark this as the answer yet, let's let the wiser SQL Server admins here speak their own experience, maybe I'm just plain dumb and missing something fairly obvious :-).